# How can I delete ground that is behind the player and out of view?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a cube that bounces forward and each time that it goes forwards more ground is added. What I want is to make it so that each time the player bounces further forward the ground that the player has past and can no longer see is destroyed. However I am not sure how to do this. Here is my code so far:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Generation : MonoBehaviour {

public GameObject Water;
public GameObject Road;
public GameObject Grass;

int firstRand;
int secondRand;
int disPlayer = 1;

Vector3 intPos = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);


// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    if (Input.GetButtonDown ("up")) {

        firstRand = Random.Range (1, 4);
        if (firstRand == 1) {
            secondRand = Random.Range (1, 5);
            for (int i = 0; i < secondRand; i++) {
                intPos = new Vector3 (0, 0, disPlayer + 3);
                disPlayer+=3;
                GameObject GrassIns = Instantiate (Grass) as GameObject;
                GrassIns.transform.position = intPos;


            }
        }
        if (firstRand == 2) {
            secondRand = Random.Range (1, 5);
            for (int i = 0; i < secondRand; i++) {
                intPos = new Vector3 (0, 0, disPlayer + 3);
                disPlayer+=3;
                GameObject RoadIns = Instantiate (Road) as GameObject;
                RoadIns.transform.position = intPos;
            }


        }
        if (firstRand == 3) {
            secondRand = Random.Range (1, 5);
            for (int i = 0; i < secondRand; i++) {
                intPos = new Vector3 (0, 0, disPlayer + 3);
                disPlayer+=3;
                GameObject WaterIns = Instantiate (Water) as GameObject;
                WaterIns.transform.position = intPos;

            }



        }
    }
}

}
```

Comment: You left too many things out. Is this 2D or 3D game? Maybe should upload a picture of the ground and the player....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most simple solution would be to add a game object with a collider as a child of your player. Place it behind enough out of viez so that when the platform enters the collider, you destroy it and it does not show.